# Ruby on Rails - Has Many, Through: find multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I realised its quite difficult to explain my problem with only words, so i'm going to use an example to describe what i am trying to do instead.

So for example:

```
#model Book 
has_many: book_genres
has_many: genres, through: :book_genres

#model Genre
has_many: book_genres
has_many: books, through: :book_genres
```

So finding books that belong to one genre only would be relatively straightforward, such as:

```
#method in books model

def self.find_books(genre)
  @g = Genre.where('name LIKE ?' , "#{genre}").take
  @b = @g.books
  #get all the books that are of that genre
end
```

So in rails console i can do `Book.find_books("Fiction")` and then i would get all the books that are of `fiction` genre.

But how can i find all the books that are both "Young Adult" and "Fiction" ? Or what if i would like to query for books that have 3 genres, such as "Young Adult", "Fiction" and "Romance" ?

I could do `g = Genre.where(name: ["Young Adult", "Fiction", "Romance"])` but subsequent to that i cannot do `g.books` and get all the books that are related to this 3 genres.

I am actually quite bad with active record so im not even sure if theres a better way to query through `Books` directly instead of finding `Genre` then finding all books that are associated with it.

But what i cannot wrap my head around is how do i get all the books that have multiple (specific)genres?

UPDATE:

So the current answers provided `Book.joins(:genres).where("genres.name" => ["Young Adult", "Fiction", "Romance"])` works, but the problem is it returns all books that has the genre of `Young Adult` OR `Fiction` OR `Romance`.

What query do i pass so that the books return has ALL 3 Genres and not only 1 or 2 out of the 3?

Comment: I would to suggest use HABTM association between book and genre.

Comment: @Sajan that still doesnt explain/answer my question. how do i achieve my desired query results?

Comment: Perhaps (untested code): `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from books inner join genres on books.genre_id = genres.id where genres.name like 'fiction' intersect select * from books inner join genres on books.genre_id = genres.id where genres.name like 'romance'")`. You may need to tweak the inner join condition.

Comment: Then you can use `values` to get an array of books.

Comment: Is the only way to pass the query to use SQL instead of using active record methods?

Comment: AFAIK, activerecord doesn't support `intersect`, but you can try [arel](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel%2FSelectManager%3Aintersect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Matching any of the given genres

The following should work for both an Array and a String:

```
Book.joins(:genres).where("genres.name" => ["Young Adult", "Fiction", "Romance"])
Book.joins(:genres).where("genres.name" => "Young Adult")
```

In general, it's better to pass a Hash to `where`, rather than trying to write a SQL snippet yourself.

See the Rails Guides for more details:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

#### Matching all of the given genres with one query

A single query could be built and then passed to `.find_by_query`:

```
def self.in_genres(genres)
  sql = genres.
    map { |name| Book.joins(:genres).where("genres.name" => name) }.
    map { |relation| "(#{relation.to_sql})" }.
    join(" INTERSECT ")

  find_by_sql(sql)
end
```

This means that calling `Book.in_genres(["Young Adult", "Fiction", "Romance"])` will run a query that looks something like this:

```
(SELECT books.* FROM books INNER JOIN … WHERE genres.name = 'Young Adult')
INTERSECT
(SELECT books.* FROM books INNER JOIN … WHERE genres.name = 'Fiction')
INTERSECT
(SELECT books.* FROM books INNER JOIN … WHERE genres.name = 'Romance');
```

It has the upside of letting the database do the heavy lifting of combining the result sets.

The downside is that we're using raw SQL, so we can't chain this with other ActiveRecord methods, for example `Books.order(:title).in_genres(["Young Adult", "Fiction"])` will ignore the `ORDER BY` clause we've tried to add.

We're also manipulating SQL queries as strings. It's possible we could avoid this using Arel, but the way Rails and Arel handle binding query values makes this pretty complicated.

#### Matching all of the given genres with multiple query

It's also possible to use multiple queries:

```
def self.in_genres(genres)
  ids = genres.
    map { |name| Book.joins(:genres).where("genres.name" => name) }.
    map { |relation| relation.pluck(:id).to_set }.
    inject(:intersection).to_a

  where(id: ids)
end
```

This means that calling `Book.in_genres(["Young Adult", "Fiction", "Romance"])` will run four queries that look something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM books INNER JOIN … WHERE genres.name = 'Young Adult';
SELECT id FROM books INNER JOIN … WHERE genres.name = 'Fiction';
SELECT id FROM books INNER JOIN … WHERE genres.name = 'Romance';
SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN (1, 3, …);
```

The downside here is that for N genres, we're making N+1 queries. The upside is that this can be combined with other ActiveRecord methods; `Books.order(:title).in_genres(["Young Adult", "Fiction"])` will do our genre filtering, and sort by title.

Comment: Its not working exactly like i would like it to although i can see why. It returns all books that are at least One of these genres ["Young Adult", "Fiction", "Romance"]. Is it possible to return all books that have All 3 of those genres instead?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some other options

Comment: Works like a charm. Clean and simple too. Thank you for the comprehensive answer as well (and taking the effort to update the answer)! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this but I think it will work

```
Book.joins(:genres).where("genres.name IN (?)", ["Young Adult", "Fiction", "Romance"])
```

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't work. It's throwing a syntax error. Its not accepting the `:` after "genres.name". I've tried other variations which i thought might work, the only one seems to be `Book.joins(:genres).where("genres.name LIKE ?", "Fiction")`. Trying to pass in an array throws an error as well.

Comment: Same "problem" as answer provided by georgebrock. Returns books that has either "Young Adult/Fiction/Romance", and not strictly only books that have all 3 genres. Any idea how to return all books that Must contain those 3 genres?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it in SQL:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    books
WHERE   id IN (
  SELECT  bg.book_id
  FROM    book_genres bg
  INNER JOIN genres g
  ON      g.id = bg.genre_id
  WHERE   g.name LIKE 'Young Adult'
  INTERSECT
  SELECT  bg.book_id
  FROM    book_genres bg
  INNER JOIN genres g
  ON      g.id = bg.genre_id
  WHERE   g.name LIKE 'Fiction'
  INTERSECT
  ...
)
```

The inner query will contain only books belonging to **all** the genres you ask about.

Here is how I'd do it in ActiveRecord:

```
# book.rb
def self.in_genres(genre_names)
  subquery = genre_names.map{|n|
    <<-EOQ
      SELECT  bg.book_id
      FROM    book_genres bg
      INNER JOIN genres g
      ON      g.id = bg.genre_id
      WHERE   g.name LIKE ?
    EOQ
  }.join("\nINTERSECT\n")
  where(<<-EOQ, *genre_names)
    id IN (
      #{subquery}
    )
  EOQ
end
```

Note that I am using `?` to avoid [sql injection vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which is a problem in the code you proposed in your question.

Another approach would be to use multiple `EXISTS` conditions with correlated sub-queries:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    books
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM   book_genres bg
                INNER JOIN genres g
                ON     g.id = bg.genre_id
                WHERE  g.name LIKE 'Young Adult'
                AND    bg.book_id = books.id)
AND     EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM   book_genres bg
                INNER JOIN genres g
                ON     g.id = bg.genre_id
                WHERE  g.name LIKE 'Fiction'
                AND    bg.book_id = books.id)
AND ...
```

You'd construct this query in ActiveRecord similarly to the first approach. I'm not sure which would be faster, so you could try both if you like.

Here is yet another way to do the SQL---possibly fastest:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    books
WHERE   id IN (
  SELECT bg.book_id
  FROM   book_genres bg
  INNER JOIN genres g
  ON     g.id = bg.genre_id
  WHERE  (g.name LIKE 'Young Adult' OR g.name LIKE 'Fiction' OR ...)
  GROUP BY bg.book_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT bg.genre_id) >= 2 -- or 3, or whatever
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! Is the best (only?) way going about this problem to use SQL instead of ActiveRecord (There's an answer that states doing in ActiveRecord but uses SQL syntax too)? As in, I am not proficient with SQL at all as well, so I would be spending some time familiarising myself with SQL and its syntax before being able to properly implement your suggested answers. Cheers :)

Comment: You should learn SQL. ActiveRecord is great because it has many "escape hatches" letting you mix raw SQL with your expressions, so you can use both together. All 3 of my SQL solutions are compatible with AR. In the first one I show how to define an AR [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) that you can combine with other AR methods, e.g. `Book.in_genres(["Fiction"]).where(author: a)` or `author.books.in_genres(["Fiction"])`. You can encapsulate the other 2 approaches in a scope the same way.

Comment: Also, a great way to debug AR problems is to print the SQL it's using, using the `to_sql` method. E.g. `q = Book.in_genres(["Fiction"]).where(author: a).includes(publisher: [:city]); Rails.logger.debug q.to_sql`

Comment: Yes i am definitely gonna learn the basic fundamentals/syntax of SQL and implement your solution. Thank you! :)

Comment: Here is a talk I gave about using SQL with ActiveRecord: https://github.com/pjungwir/rails-and-sql-talk

Comment: Personally when I have a complicated query, I write it in SQL first, then work out the AR translation. It seems less complicated to deal with one layer at a time. Also, knowing SQL is good for your career, because it is the lingua franca of the back end, just like Javascript is the lingua franca of the front. Whether you're using Rails or Django or JEE or .Net or whatever, you will probably have some SQL.

Comment: Really appreciate the advice! Would look up the talk you gave as well. Thank you so much! (Not sure if you feel the bounty is relevant but i would leave the question open for now!) Cheers :)