# Rails 7 many-to-many relationship, search for items with multiple related items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

Assuming I have three models, some items, identifiers and a joining model in Rails 7

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_identifiers
  has_many :identifiers, through: :item_identifiers
end

class ItemIdentifier < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :identifier
end

class Identifier < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_identifiers
  has_many :items, through: :item_identifiers
end
```

With this I can access the identifiers from the items with

```rb
item.identifiers
```

and I can search the db for an item with an identifier

```rb
Item.joins(:identifiers).where("`identifiers`.`desc` LIKE %foo%")
```

Assuming I have an item and it has two identifiers
`foo` `bar`
and I have the following searches

```rb
search1 = ["oo"]
search2 = ["foo", "ar"]
search3 = ["fo", "baz"]
```

How do I go about finding items with multiple identifiers.
Based on the search arrays above, both search1 and search2 should find the item, but search3 should not.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after much more searching [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455920/ruby-on-rails-has-many-through-find-multiple-conditions#42458975)

The solution is to add the following to my items model

```rb
    def self.with_identifiers(identifiers)
        sql = identifiers.
          map { |identifier| Item.joins(identifiers).where("identifiers.desc LIKE ?", "%#{identifier}%") }.
          map { |relation| "(#{relation.to_sql})" }.
          join(" INTERSECT ")
      
        find_by_sql(sql)
      end
```

and search using the following

```rb
Item.with_identifiers(search1)
```

Comment: this can be a solution but it might  spam your system with requests to DB, so use with caution :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to filter by a combination of identifiers then you need to use `UNION` or `SELECT FROM SELECT`.

`Union` can join two different selects and is a better option, but Rails does not have a beautiful solution for that and needs to use Arel table. here is an example: [Obtain Union all result in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57491185/obtain-union-all-result-in-activerecord)

`Select from Select` is worse solution, because Rails dont have any normal way to do that apart from creating a `VIEW` and then selecting from it. so the only thing you can do using this approach is just using pure SQL to make the request.

As an alternative you can drop the `LIKE` statement and use just normal `WHERE identifier = 'foo' AND identifier = 'bar'`, but for that you need to pass the exact identifiers.

**WRAPUP**

In my opinion - `UNION` would be the correct solution, so i would advise you to learn abit about Arel tables cause it is a very powerfool tool. Here is some links for that:

https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Arel/Table

https://devhints.io/arel

Comment: Assuming item1 has identifiers ```foo``` and ```bar``` and item2 has ```bar``` and ```baz```. search3 with ```UNION``` will return both results will it not? I want to use ```INTERSECT``` not ```UNION```, correct?

AREL looks like a very useful library, so I will defintely be taking a look at that

Comment: yes, you are correct